# apply a function which contains group_by within dplyr funciton to datalist in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr, lapply, datalist

I have a data.list like so:

```
list(structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), species = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L), .Label = 
c("Apiaceae", 
"Ceyperaceae", "Magnoliaceae", "Vitaceae"), class = "factor"), 
N = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-24L)), structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), species = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L), .Label = 
c("Apiaceae", 
"Ceyperaceae", "Magnoliaceae", "Vitaceae"), class = "factor"), 
N = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-24L)))
```

I want to apply my.fun which was written within dplyr package to this list of data. First, I grouped data by "group" and get an output of the function which has already in R and then I applied this function to the data list. But output is 0. there isn't any output. Can you help me to find out the mistake?

```
 my.fun <- function(x, y){
    group_by(x, !!as.name(group)) %>%
    mutate(out = diversity(N, "shannon")) 
 }

check <- lapply(colnames(list), function(x) {
  my.fun(x$group, x$N)
})
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where is the `y` parameter inside your `my.fun`.  Also, if there is no `group` parameter, then you can directly use `group_by(x, group)` as `group` is a column name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that we are passing group column and the column going on which `diversity` is applied as strings,

```
library(tidyverse)
library(vegan)
my.fun <- function(data, grpCol, divCol) {
       data %>% 
           group_by_at(grpCol) %>%
           mutate(out = diversity(!! rlang::sym(divCol), "shannon"))
           #or use mutate_at
           # mutate_at(vars(divCol), list(out = ~ diversity(., "shannon")))
    }

map(lst1, my.fun, grpCol = "group", divCol = "N")
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 24 x 4
# Groups:   group [3]
#   group species          N   out
#   <int> <fct>        <int> <dbl>
# 1     1 Magnoliaceae     2  1.75
# 2     1 Magnoliaceae     2  1.75
# 3     1 Apiaceae         3  1.75
# 4     1 Magnoliaceae     2  1.75
# 5     1 Magnoliaceae     2  1.75
# 6     1 Ceyperaceae      1  1.75
# 7     2 Magnoliaceae     2  2.06
# 8     2 Apiaceae         3  2.06
# 9     2 Magnoliaceae     2  2.06
#10     2 Apiaceae         3  2.06
# … with 14 more rows

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 24 x 4
# Groups:   group [3]
#   group species          N   out
#   <int> <fct>        <int> <dbl>
# 1     1 Magnoliaceae     2  1.75
# 2     1 Magnoliaceae     2  1.75
# 3     1 Apiaceae         3  1.75
# 4     1 Magnoliaceae     2  1.75
# 5     1 Magnoliaceae     2  1.75
# 6     1 Ceyperaceae      1  1.75
# 7     2 Magnoliaceae     2  2.06
# 8     2 Apiaceae         3  2.06
# 9     2 Magnoliaceae     2  2.06
#10     2 Apiaceae         3  2.06
# … with 14 more rows
```

Note that

```
identical(lst1[[1]], lst1[[2]])
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you akrun so much! I have a little bit problem to define the group variable. Can we integrate another function (group = my.fun0(x)) after data %>% inside of this my.function?

Comment: @SunRise You can do that only thing is the `my.fun0(x)` should return a string name for the grouping column

Comment: @SunRise Also, not sure how the `my.fun0(x)` assuming 'x' is data would automatically return the name of the grouping column.  It should have some other parameter as well.  In addition, not clear why you wanted to make multiple function calls

Comment: because group variable should be defined for datalist (for every datasets in this list). x is a column in each datasets which has a name of B_value.

Comment: @SunRise Let's say you have 'group1', 'group2'  as column name for each list element, and it is a vector of user input values, then instead of `map` use `map2` i.e. `map2(lst1, c("group1", "group2"),  grpCol = .y, divCol = .N)`

Comment: Actually I obtained it like so: group <- lapply(list, my.fun0). But when I run above code you defined, it says there is no variable: group.  That's why I wanted to include it into my.fun

Comment: @SunRise  It should be `map2(lst1, c("group1", "group2"), ~ my.fun(.x, grpCol = .y, divCol = "N"))`  Here, I changed `names(lst1[[1]])[1] <- "group1";
 names(lst1[[2]])[1] <- "group2"`  Using the same `my.fun` in my post

Comment: my real data list contains 20 datasets inside of it. Should I continue "group1", "group2"...until "group20"?

Comment: @SunRise  Yes, you can have a vector `v1 <- paste0("group", 1:20)` and use that as `map2(lst1, v1, ~`

Comment: it is me again. How can I combine all the datasets in the list into a single data?

Comment: @SunRise you can use `bind_rows(yourlst)`